# Conditions when 'diagonal" of bilinear function is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\varphi:V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bilinear symmetric function. Let $U=\{a\in V: \varphi(a,a)=0\}$. Prove that $U$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if one of the index of inertia of $\varphi$ is equal to zero.

**Proof:**

$\Rightarrow$ Denote by $p$ and $q$ positive and negative index of inertia of $\varphi$. Suppose by contradiction that $p>0$ and $q>0$. Then there is some basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ of $V$ such that the matrix $B$ of $\varphi$ in this basis is diagonal and $B=\text{diag}(1,\dots,1,-1,\dots,-1,0,\dots,0)$ where we have $p$ copies of $1$ and $q$ copies of $-1$.

It is easy to see that $U=\langle e_{p+q+1},\dots,e_n\rangle$. Since $p,q>0$ let's consider the vector $v:=e_1+e_{p+1}$ and  easy to see that $v\notin U$ because $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is a basis of $V$.

But $\varphi(v,v)=\varphi(e_1,e_1)+\varphi(e_{p+1},e_{p+1})+2\varphi(e_1,e_{p+1})=1+(-1)+2\times 0=0$ which tells us that $v\in U$, which is a contradiction.

$\Leftarrow$ WLOG let $q=0$ then $p\geq0$. If $p=0$ then $U=V$ obviously .

Assume that $p>0$ then $\varphi(x,y)=x_1y_1+\dots+x_py_p$. It is easy to see that if $a\in U$ then for $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ one can show that $\varphi(\lambda a, \lambda a)=\lambda^2\varphi(a,a)=0$, which means that $\lambda a\in U$.

Let's take $a,b\in U$ then $a_1^2+\dots+a_p^2=0$ and $b_1^2+\dots+b_p^2=0$ then one can show that $$(a_1b_1+\dots+a_pb_p)^2\leq (a_1^2+\dots+a_p^2)(b_1^2+\dots+b_p^2)$$ and it follows that $a_1b_1+\dots+a_pb_p=0$, which means that $ab\in U$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

Does this proof look good?

I have spent some time on the direction $\Rightarrow$ when I realized that i need to consider the vector $e_1+e_{p+1}$.

Comment: The proof of $\implies$ is not correct. You claim $U$ is generated by $e_{p+q+1},...,e_{n}$, which is not the case. Then show an element $e_{1}+e_{p+1}$ which is in $U$ and obtain a contradiction with the first fact, which being false doesn't force you to conclude that $p,q>0$ is false. You could look at $e_{1}+e_{p+1}$ and to $e_1-e_{p+1}$. Both are in $U$ and their sum is $2e_1$, which for characteristic $\neq2$ is not in $U$.

Comment: @lepidon, could you give more details why my claim that $U$ is generated by $e_{p+q+1},\dots,e_n$ is false? From your comment it is not clear to me. Also I did not understand this sentence at all "Then show an element $e_1+e_{p+1}$
 which is in $U$ and obtain a contradiction with the first fact, which being false doesn't force you to conclude that $p,q>0$  is false."

Comment: You proved it yourself. $e_1+e_{p+1}$ is in $U$ by direct computation, and it is not generated by $e_{p+q+1},...,e_n$. So, the claim that $U$ is generated by those, which you made without any argument, is false. In the quoted sentence I am only saying that you have two assumptions, $p,q>0$ and $U$ generated by $e_{p+q+1},...,e_n$, and get a 'contradiction'. Since the second assumption is already false, then you cannot conclude anything about the assumption that $p$ and $q$ are non-zero.

Comment: @lepidon, I guess you are right. But it can be corrected in this way: Since we can show that $e_1+e_{p+1}$ and $e_1-e_{p+1}$ are in $U$ then their sum $2e_1$ is also in $U$ but it is not true since $\varphi(e_1,e_1)=1\neq 0$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I said in the first comment. Note that that works because in the field of coefficients, which is $\mathbb{R}$ in your case, $2\neq 0$. On fields like $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ that wouldn't work.

Comment: @lepidon, that's true. Thanks a lot for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: Btw, can you help me with my two last questions on linear algebra please? No one replied yet :(